# Where are files downloaded in Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a backend Nodejs application and I am fetching and streaming files in the background when a certain event happens in the client.
I have deployed the backend to Google App Engine.
The file downloading is working fine but I am a bit confused where the files are downloaded and stored ? In the app I am creating a folder relative to the deployed app folder and storing them there with createWriteStream. I also init a git repository where the files are (using simple-git npm module)

It seems the files are not accessible via the cloud shell since I can not find them there

Can I for example create a storage bucket and use "normal" file operations command there (and init the repo there)

-Jani

Answer (score 0):

To store data downloaded you want to store it in Cloud Storage, you can find a complete guide in this [Using Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage) documentation.

Under almost any circumstances you want to download files into the App Engine Deployment since the instances doesn't have much memory to store data, and also when the deployment scales up and down you are prone to lost data

Comment: Do you know can I init a repo in google storage with https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git ? For example like this:
`require('simple-git')().init().add('./*').commit("first commit!");`

Comment: Cloud Storage have built in [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) if that is what you are looking for. You don't need any external library to do so.

Comment: It seems that the object versioning does not meet my requirements. I would need to init a git repo (there will be multiple repos), download files to the repo and get the unified diff between the commits. All this works fine locally but the problem is now when I want to deploy this to the cloud.

Comment: Hey, I think what are you trying to do is not the intended usage of App Engine Flex. For That, I suggest that you create an Cloud Compute Instance and deploy your application from there. In this way you will have more control on your folder structure.

Comment: You could manage to do the git thingy in the temporary folder of App Engine but keep in mind that this goes against the design principle of App Engine which is to be stateless. When the App Engine instance restart everything will dissapear from your folder.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into that Compute Engine thing and it seems the best option. However there is a lot to configure to get it up and running properly.

Comment: There is another option, you can use [Gfuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse?hl=es-419) to turn the Cloud Storage Buckets into folders. However, fuse it's a lot slower than Cloud Storage